# Custom available dates bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to show only custom dates with bootstrap datepicker: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html.

Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "only custom dates"?

Comment: For example I want to show available only "22-05-2015", "23-05-2015". The rest of dates will be unavailable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`beforeShowDay`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#beforeshowday)**:

```
var dateDisabled = ["2014-5-5", "2014-5-6"];
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(
    {
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        beforeShowDay: function(date)
        {
            if ($.inArray(date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate(), dateDisabled) !== -1)
            {
                return;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svierkant/jhnk8/1/)**

Comment: I found a little bug: When I put some text in the input of datepicker, automatically appears today date.

Comment: @JuanDelÁrbol You are right! Thanks for pointing that out, I'll send in a bug report.

Comment: Man ! You saved my DAY ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available under that link:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Look for the section "Disabling dates in the past and dependent disabling."

Answer (score 0):

I think instead disable past/future dates you mean enable only some picked dates, like events in a calendar. And yes: even this is possible providing an `available` function: [Bootstrap Datepicker restrict available dates to be selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146382/bootstrap-datepicker-restrict-available-dates-to-be-selected)