# jQuery datepicker available dates not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to show the available dates on the calendar but with my code below it only shows the available dates on the first month and doesn't work on the next month after. Does anybody know what the issue might be please?

```
var availableDates = $('#js-delivery-dates').data('delivery-dates').split(','),
  $deliveryDatepicker = $('.delivery-datepicker');

function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "", "Available"];
  } else {
    return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
  }
}

$deliveryDatepicker.datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  beforeShowDay: available,
  onSelect: function() {
    selected = $(this).val();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nh6eoj03/3080/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456021/custom-available-dates-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You are missing very simple stuff check this line:

```
<div id="js-delivery-dates" class="delivery-datepicker" data-delivery-dates="30-9-2018,1-10-2018,2-10-2018,3-10-2018,4-10-2018,5-10-2018">
datepicker
</div>
```

You just need to write your days as single value without preceding zero. 01-10-2018 change to 1-10-2018 as you see in my sample.

Also, here is a code prove: https://jsfiddle.net/nezir/nh6eoj03/3097/

[image]