# Gray out all but certain dates on Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I'm setting up a datepicker, but I only want the user to be able to select dates from a pre-determined date array I have populated. These are dates where relevant events happened. Nothing happened on the other dates outside of the array.

Below is an example array that I would have.

```
dateArr = ["2015-10-27", "2015-10-29", "2015-11-10", "2016-11-30", "2016-12-07", "2017-06-29", "2017-06-30", "2017-10-23", "2017-12-13", "2018-03-27", "2018-03-29", "2018-03-30", "2018-03-31", "2018-04-02", "2018-04-07", "2018-04-08", "2018-04-09"]
```

I've looked at other examples, but none seem to do what I'm trying to do. The array dates would be selectable, and the rest would be grayed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Datepicker restrict available dates to be selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146382/bootstrap-datepicker-restrict-available-dates-to-be-selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below Jquery code:

HTML Code:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Jquery Code :

```
jQuery(function(){

    var enableDays = ["7-8-2019", "13-8-2019"];

    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'd-m-yy', date)
        console.log(sdate)
        if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
            return [true];
        }
        return [false];
    }

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays});
});
```

**JFiddle Code Here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qampw1n5/